# Chrome not rendering css completely

Tags: css, google-chrome, rendering, font-face

**Edit:**

Chrome is somehow rendering the fonts i use via @font-face incorrectly. Which i found as i changed the font family of the inspected element to arial. The reason this might be, is because as i was searching for a fix on how chrome renders fonts so they appear more smooth instead of pixelated, i found that you could swap the order of the font formats and put the svg on top which would cause chrome to render it perfectly. As seen [here](http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/font-face-chrome-rendering/).

So either the order is messing them up, or simply the font is broken in some way.

Now the question is, how do i use this font without breaking the site and keeping the fonts smooth?

**Here is the @font-face code i use:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'alegreya_scregular';
    src: url('../includes/fonts/alegreyasc-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../includes/fonts/alegreyasc-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('../includes/fonts/alegreyasc-regular-webfont.svg#alegreya_scregular') format('svg'),
         url('../includes/fonts/alegreyasc-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../includes/fonts/alegreyasc-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'droid_sansregular';
    src: url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.svg#droid_sansregular') format('svg'),
         url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'droid_sansbold';
    src: url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-bold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-bold-webfont.svg#droid_sansbold') format('svg'),
         url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

---

I have some rendering issues on chrome. For some reason, the links right side gets cut off so the underlines will only fill half the of text, and the divs on the right side will not break off the words to a new line. It only happens some of the time and if i refresh the page a couple of times (differs how many times) it will fix itself eventually. Images are below.

Note: The site is in danish.

Images, underlined the issues in red:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJHXD.jpg

What causes this, and how do i fix it?

---

**Note: This is for the navigation links**

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="first"></li>
    <li><a href="forside.html">Forside</a></li>
    <li><a href="booking.html">Booking</a></li>
    <li><a href="galleri.html">Galleri</a></li>
    <li><a href="begivenheder.html">Begivenheder</a></li>
    <li><a href="events.html">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="politik.html">Politik</a></li>
    <li><a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.header .nav {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: .70em;
    bottom: -8px;
    right: 16px;
}
.header .nav li {
    float: left;
    background: #171717 url(../images/site/nav_divider.png) repeat-y right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
} .header .nav li:hover {
    background: #1a1a1a url(../images/site/nav_divider.png) repeat-y right;
}

.header .nav .first {
    width:2px;
    height:31px;
    margin-bottom:-0.95em;
}

.header .nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: .75em .85em .75em .75em;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: without knowing your html and css code it is not really possible to answer

Comment: looks like incorrect markup (e.g. missing closing tags) and/or messy css. You need to post the faulty markup and the css affecting those elements.

Comment: @Christoph Alright, will try and upload the html and css

Comment: @Christoph Alright, i updated the page with the css and html.

Comment: does your markup validate?

Comment: @ScottSimpson My CSS validates completely with some prefix warnings. My HTML have few errors, but are just missing alts and unecessary facebook iframe attributes.

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with em sizing and padding and some other CSS on your page.

Comment: examine the css-styles in the elements view of the devtools and have a look for inherited styles and also check the computed styles. Perhaps some rule precedence problem (may also happen when using boilerplates).

Comment: Seems like the padding isn't an issue when i inspect the element, but the size of the content of the element gets reduced down to a half or one third of its size.

Comment: Oh wow, i think i know what is causing the issue. I think it might be the font i'm using. When i change it to arial in the developer tools it works. I'm using @font-face, will update post with the font-face.

Comment: @Christoph So i've added the font-face code which i believe has been bugging the site, to the main post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching on @font-face and chrome behaviour, i found a solution to the problem. Apparently moving the svg to the top will make the rendered font break the layout, so instead you should keep the original formatting and add a special media query, which will render the font smoothly in chrome while not breaking the layout.

**Example:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'droid_sansregular';
    src: url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.svg#droid_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

}

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'droid_sansregular';
        src: url('../includes/fonts/droidsans-webfont.svg#droid_sansregular') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
}
```